# I create main folder is new in that i also sub folders. I would to print sub dir data

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, data-science

new is the main name of the folder, there are still 3subfloders in that main folder. my question is - I would print like the "path and data also"?

```
import OS

import pandas as pd

import glob

files = OS.listdir("/home/rugved/new")

print(files)

full_data = pd.DataFrame()

for file in files:

    path = "/home/rugved/new" +  file + "/*.csv"

    mod = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(f) for f in glob.glob(path)], ignore_index = True)

    full_data = full_data.append(mod)

print(full_data)
```

---

### Traceback is-
['abc', 'ghi', 'def']

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_56324/2862949528.py in 
9 for file in files:
10     path = "/home/rugved/new" +  file + "/*.csv"
---> 11     mod = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(f) for f in glob.glob(path)], ignore_index = True)
12     full_data = full_data.append(mod)
13

/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pandas/core/reshape/concat.py in concat(objs, axis, join, join_axes, ignore_index, keys, levels, names, verify_integrity, sort, copy)
242     ValueError: Indexes have overlapping values: ['a']
243     """
--> 244     op = _Concatenator(
245         objs,
246         axis=axis,

/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pandas/core/reshape/concat.py in **init**(self, objs, axis, join, join_axes, keys, levels, names, ignore_index, verify_integrity, copy, sort)
302
303         if len(objs) == 0:
--> 304             raise ValueError("No objects to concatenate")
305
306         if keys is None:

ValueError: No objects to concatenate

Answer (score 0):

you can use the

> os.walk()

This is brief documentation; I hope it works:

```
import os
if __name__ == "__main__":
    for (root,dirs,files) in os.walk(<main_folder_dir>, topdown=true):
        print (root)
        print (dirs)
        print (files)
        print ('--------------------------------')
```